# Converting MySQL datetime to very specific format for export

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I need to convert data from a MySQL to a very specific datetime format so that it can be automatically integrated into a client's database on a regular basis.

I would like to know if there is a way to convert the usual MySQL timestamp in format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss (e.g. 2012-01-10 10:58:07) to a very specific string that describes the date/time format like dd-Mos-yy hh:mm:ss.sss (e.g. 07-Sep-10 12:00:00.000). The new date/time format has to be *exact*, down to the millisecond values.

I know there are some clever ways to manipulate incoming data to put a string into the datetime format MySQL can accept, but I cannot seem to find the same tools for exporting data. I would like to handle most of this using SQL, but have some knowledge of PHP if that is a better tool to use.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(date,format) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'll have to append it to whatever MySQL provides.

Comment: Would the `CONCAT()` function be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Just use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) when you are creating the MySQL query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%b-%y %H:%m:%s.%f') as date_formatted FROM your_table;
```

This handles microseconds as well using the `%f` option but that provides 6 digits & not 3 digits as your question specs out. If you genuinely know the date will need 3 digits for the milliseconds, you can use [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to just return the string date data you need. This should work

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%b-%y %H:%m:%s.%f'),1,22) as date_formatted FROM your_table;
```

But you can also fudge 3 digits by just explicitly setting 3 `0`’s after the time like so:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%b-%y %H:%m:%s.000') as date_formatted FROM your_table;
```

Note how the `%f` is now `.000`. But that said, that is not millisecond precision since the `.000` is simply appended as text & not based on real data. At least `%f` is working with real date data.

So if based on the examples above `DATE_FORMAT` is not 100% perfect for your needs perhaps using PHP date formatting would be the best way to handle. If that is the case, the date/time data would be stored as a Unix timestamp?  Or as just a timestamp?

If it’s just a timestamp, using [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) would convert it:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as date_unixtimestamp FROM your_table;
```

Then take that `date_unixtimestamp` and format as you wish in PHP.

Comment: Amazing! You're my hero JakeGould! I spent an entire day trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Where will you get the millisecond information from if you didn't have it already? You need to set the milliseconds to '000' - hardcoded. Now its simple like that:

```
echo date('dd-Mos-yy hh:mm:ss', strtotime($mysql_time)) . '000';
```

I would also make sure, that the other database server is using the same timezone as you. Otherwise you might have to convert the time before.

Comment: yeap :) I like your solution more if it is sure that the code will run on mysql only, because the work get's done were it should, in the database server. But I'm not sure how portable `DATE_CONVERT()` is between several SQL database engines. Would be worth to have a look..